# Width previous element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to take the width of the elements before an element in hover.

I tried with:

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
$(this).prevAll().each(function() {
    var margin = $(this).width();
});
$(this).css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
});
```

But the console say:

Uncaught ReferenceError: margin is not defined

Any solution?
Thanks

Comment: don't take `prevAll`. What html element you want to have margin-left?

Comment: 1.The variable `margin` does not exist in the function scope. That's why it says the reference does not exist. You should define `margin` in the function scope.   2.What you do in this code: `$(this).prevAll().each(function() {
    var margin = $(this).width();
});` is going over all the previous elements (and not only one) and assigning their width value to margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm looking for a way to **take the width of the elements** before an element in hover.*

You need to initialize your var outside of loop and just add the values:

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
  var margin = 0;
  $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
    margin += $(this).width();
  });
  $(this).css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing margin variable outside of each function would be result in undefined. Store the variable out of the each function scope so that you can access it outside the scope:

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
  var margin;
  $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
    margin = $(this).width();
  });
  $(this).css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
});
```

---

But I can realize in the above case, you won't get list margin-left accordingly what you're trying to do. So, you may use like this:

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
  var $this = $(this);//'li'
  $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
    var margin = $(this).width();
    $this.css('margin-left', margin + 'px');//margin on 'li'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your margin variable outside of the scope where you define or set the value.

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
    var that = this;
    $(that).prevAll().each(function() {
        var margin = $(this).width();
        $(this).css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the margin inside the loop where the margin variable is defined. If a veriable is define in a function/loop then the 'scope' of this variable is the function/loop that it is contained in.

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
    $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
        var margin = $(this).width();
        $(this).css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
    });
});
```

If you want to use margin outside the loop then you need to define it before like this:

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
    var margin = 0;
    $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
        margin = $(this).width();
    });
    $(this).css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
});
```

and for a full page scope, define before you do anything:

```
var margin = 0;
$('ul li').hover(function() {
    $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
        margin = $(this).width();
    });
    $(this).css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
}); 

//margin can also be used here now.
```

I think the first solution is what you are looking for in this instance but I have given the second in case you come across something similar again.